# Routers gateway address is not advertised in the dhcp offer packet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have an wireless router with only my XP PC connected to the LAN port. WAN port is connected to internet. DHCP is enabled on the router. I have configured router LAN IP as   192.168.1.1 and gateway as 192.168.1.33. Upon debugging dhcp offer packet from the router, i am seeing OPTION ROUTER(code 3) is advertised as 192.168.1.1 and not the gateway 192.168.1.33. So LAN PC network params are updated with the gateway ip as 192.168.1.1. I want to know whether this is an expected behavior or not ? Is it not that Router must advertise the gateway as 192.168.1.33 in the offer packet? Also there is no host in the LAN   which got IP as 192.168.1.33, i just simply configured it as default gateway on the router.

```
                 ----------------------
                |                      |
                |                      |
                 ---------------------
(192.168.1.1)       L  L  L  L       W (IP 10.130.64.100) (DG 10.130.64.1)  
(DHCP enabled)       |                |   
(pool 1.100 - 1.200) |                |  
(DG option -         |                |    
 - 192.168.1.33)     |                |  
                    PC              Internet(IP 10.130.64.1)  
            (IP 192.168.1.100)  
            (DG 192.168.1.1)  
L - LAN port  
W - WAN port

LAN DG option is configurable on router. So i just simply configured some same 
subnet IP(192.168.1.33) and checking it on PC.
```

Comment: Is this just a regular consumer router? If that is the case your router should only have one LAN interface IP, which should be the same as the gateway that the DHCP service advertises inside your network.

Comment: 1. The router cannot have two interfaces on the same layer 3 subnet (assuming a /24 subnet mask on both interfaces). 2. The router's DG is only the router's DG. The computer's DG is the LAN ip address of the router, not the WAN ip address of the router.

Comment: @joeqwerty. Thanks for your views. DG I am talking is not the gateway address got to the router from WAN port. This is an gateway address that can be advertised to LAN DHCP clients. There is an option to configure DG along with LAN IP address and DHCP pool on the router. So is is correct that this DG must also be advertised to LAN clients in the DHCP offer message ?

Comment: @user3050461 .Thanks for responding. This is an wireless ISP router mostly used by small sized customers.

Comment: If 192.168.1.33 is the ip address for the WAN port of the router then that `is not` the right ip address to use as the DG for the LAN clients. If 192.168.1.1 is the ip address for the LAN port of the router than that `is` the right ip address to use as the DG for the LAN clients. Can you post a network diagram showing the ip addresses on both router interfaces?

Comment: The WAN and LAN interfaces on the router cannot be numbered inside the same subnet if you expect the router to route. What device is assigned 192.168.1.33?

Comment: There is no device on LAN with 192.168.1.33. Just simply configuring it on router and checking it on PC.

Comment: If your DHCP server has an option to specify a DG but advertises a different DG, then I would say this isn't so much a networking problem as a problem administering this particular router. Generally speaking, a DHCP server can advertise any IP you want as a DG, whether or not a device with that IP address exists. It's possible your router/firmware may have a bug that has gone unfixed, as the vast majority of people using an ISP's router will just want to use the router's LAN IP as the DG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router should not let you think you can override what it advertises as the default gateway address via DCHP, when in actuality it will ignore your override attempt and advertise its own IP address as the default gateway.

Your router has a bug.

Whether the problem is in the UI (letting you try to do this, when it's not possible) or the DHCP server (for not making it possible to do what you're trying), is a matter for debate.

I will say, though, that it seems to me that leaving NAT on, but overriding the default gateway that the DHCP server advertises, is a strange configuration. A good UI should at least warn you that your NAT router can't be a NAT router unless the clients use it as their router, and suggest that you either stop trying to do the override, or that you turn off NAT if you're not going to use it.